# When Kyle Reese is in the store, trying to evade the cops, how do they not hear the clatter of the hanger he puts down?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator

When Kyle Reese is in the mall, trying to evade the cops, he drops a hanger from the clothes he's stealing.

Why didn't the cop/s hear it landing? It makes the scene a bit unrealistic as we can hear it on camera, yet no cops within distance were able to hear it. Remember, the camera was probably right beside him and everything else was quiet.

Answer (score 3):

In the original script, Kyle's (noisy) attempts to steal the coat were stymied by a police dog. Not only did it *hear* him but it also attacked him, followed by another policeman finding him.

> ANGLE - COP, passing the end of a long aisle B.G. while in  the F.G. a
>   hand ENTERS FRAME, removing a knit shirt from a hanger.  Reese slips
>   the shirt on quietly and does a fast crab-walk across the aisles to
>   melt into the other racks and shadows, CAMERA MOVING LOW with him.
>
> CUT TO:
>   **13      INT. DEPARTMENT STORE/AISLE - NIGHT                    13**
>   With a shocking GROWL the police dog hurtles out of the shadows,
>   LEAPING RIGHT AT CAMERA.
>
> ANGLE - REESE AND DOG, a dark blur with teeth, extremely Doberman,
>   flies toward Reese.  He spins.  Catches it by the throat in mid-air.
>   Arcs it to the floor with unflinching precision.
>
> C.U. - DOBERMAN, suddenly on its back and held by the throat, THE DOG
>   YELPS and stares at Reese, who leans very close. Inches from its eyes
>   he fixes it with a gaze of uncompromising dominance.  Some ancient
>   communication seems to pass between the two.
>
> Reese releases the animal and turns his back on it, selecting a long
>   overcoat from a rack.  The dog backs away from him, stiff-legged and
>   confused.
>
> **14      INT. DEPARTMENT STORE - NIGHT                          14**
>   TRACKING WITH REESE as he rounds a corner on the run, still shrugging
>   into his long coat. Running smack at him is another cop, gun aimed.

I'm assuming that since the scene doesn't really add anything in terms of the plot (other than establishing that he has a peculiar affinity with dogs, something that doesn't come up again) that it was just cut for time/budget or because it makes him a less sympathetic character.

Comment: Valorum: Interesting. But if he runs into a cop with a gun being aimed at him, was it just that the cop did not see that he was aiming a gun at him? He was never caught in the movie and so I am guessing he was still able to escape in the novel?